# Image not found when running rails in Rubymine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, rubygems, rubymine

I'm getting the following error when trying to run some rails commands in my Rubymine. I have recently changed some permissions to get some symlinks to work although this may not be related.

For example when I run `rails c` I get this type of error.

```
RAILS_GROUPS is unset; defaulting to web,worker
/Users/paul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/pg-0.20.0/lib/pg.rb:4:in `require': dlopen(/Users/paul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/pg-0.20.0/lib/pg_ext.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/opt/postgresql/lib/libpq.5.dylib
  Reason: image not found - /Users/paul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/pg-0.20.0/lib/pg_ext.bundle (LoadError)
        from /Users/paul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/pg-0.20.0/lib/pg.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
        from /Users/paul/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in `require'
        from /Users/paul/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in `block (2 levels) in require'
        from /Users/paul/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `each'
        from /Users/paul/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block in require'
        from /Users/paul/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/bundler/runtime.rb:65:in `each'
        from /Users/paul/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/bundler/runtime.rb:65:in `require'
        from /Users/paul/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/bundler.rb:114:in `require'
        from /Users/paul/labstat1/labstat1/config/application.rb:29:in `<top (required)>'
        from /Users/paul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application.rb:92:in `require'
        from /MacBook-Pro:labstat1 paul$ Users/paul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application.rb:92:in `preload'
        from /Users/paul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application.rb:153:in `serve'
        from /Users/paul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application.rb:141:in `block in run'
        from /Users/paul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application.rb:135:in `loop'
        from /Users/paul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application.rb:135:in `run'
        from /Users/paul/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application/boot.rb:19:in `<top (required)>'
        from /Users/paul/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from /Users/paul/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't seem to be a Ruby On Rails/Rubymine issue but a MacOS one.

From https://github.com/kelaberetiv/TagUI/issues/86:

> There is a new dependency in newer versions of macOS. To fix the error do the following. It installs Homebrew (a package manager for macOS) and installs OpenSSL for https connections.
>
> If you do not have Homebrew or don't know what is Homebrew
>
> ```
> /usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
> brew update && brew upgrade
> brew uninstall openssl; brew uninstall openssl; brew install https://github.com/tebelorg/Tump/releases/download/v1.0.0/openssl.rb
> ```
>
> Or if you already have Homebrew installed
>
> ```
> brew update && brew upgrade
> brew uninstall openssl; brew uninstall openssl; brew install https://github.com/tebelorg/Tump/releases/download/v1.0.0/openssl.rb
> ```