# Image not found for patron gem when running rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, gemfile, gemfile.lock

I'm getting the following error when trying to run some `rails` commands in my app.

I upgraded ruby 2.6.6 to 2.7.3 (I use rbenv) and bundle from 2.0.2 to 2.1.4, by doing

```
 brew update && brew upgrade ruby-build
 rbenv install 2.7.3
 gem install bundler:2.1.4
 bundle install
```

And now, when I run any rails command (ex: `rails c`) I get this error:

```
/Users/asceta/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require': dlopen(/Users/asceta/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/patron-0.13.3/lib/patron/session_ext.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: @rpath/libssh2.1.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/asceta/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/patron-0.13.3/lib/patron/session_ext.bundle
  Reason: image not found - /Users/asceta/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/patron-0.13.3/lib/patron/session_ext.bundle (LoadError)
    from /Users/asceta/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    from /Users/asceta/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
    from /Users/asceta/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    from /Users/asceta/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
    from /Users/asceta/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:324:in `block in require'
    from /Users/asceta/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/asceta/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:324:in `require'
    from /Users/asceta/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/patron-0.13.3/lib/patron/session.rb:6:in `<main>'
    from /Users/asceta/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
    from /Users/asceta/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    from /Users/asceta/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
    from /Users/asceta/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    from /Users/asceta/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
    from /Users/asceta/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:324:in `block in require'
    from /Users/asceta/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/asceta/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.3.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:324:in `require'
    from /Users/asceta/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/patron-0.13.3/lib/patron.rb:5:in `<main>'
    from /Users/asceta/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
    from /Users/asceta/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    from /Users/asceta/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
    from /Users/asceta/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    from /Users/asceta/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
    from /Users/asceta/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.1.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:74:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from /Users/asceta/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.1.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:69:in `each'
    from /Users/asceta/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.1.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:69:in `block in require'
    from /Users/asceta/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.1.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:58:in `each'
    from /Users/asceta/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.1.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:58:in `require'
    from /Users/asceta/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.1.4/lib/bundler.rb:174:in `require'
    from /Users/asceta/Projects/Fintual/monolith/config/application.rb:10:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/asceta/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/application.rb:92:in `require'
    from /Users/asceta/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/application.rb:92:in `preload'
    from /Users/asceta/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/application.rb:157:in `serve'
    from /Users/asceta/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/application.rb:145:in `block in run'
    from /Users/asceta/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/application.rb:139:in `loop'
    from /Users/asceta/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/application.rb:139:in `run'
    from /Users/asceta/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/application/boot.rb:19:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/asceta/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:83:in `require'
    from /Users/asceta/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:83:in `require'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

What I've tried:

1. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59304636/15455523).
2. Re-install rbenv
3. Manually uninstalling and installing patron gem with `gem uninstall patron && gem install patron`
4. Re-install openssl with `brew reinstall openssl@1.1`

**When I manually remove the patron gem from `Gemfile` and `Gemfile.lock` everything works fine**, but I need the patron gem.

As last measure I've left to try to remove rbenv and use RVM: Ruby Version Manager, instead, but I want to avoid this and keep using rbenv

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Next things I would try:

- Running `bundle exec rails c` instead.
- Check what `which openssl` returns, that may indicate that you have different versions installed (mine shows `/usr/bin/openssl`)
- Make sure you are doing all operations from the repository directory.

Comment: It worked! I had openssl pointing to `/Users/asceta/anaconda3/bin/openssl`, I removed everything related to anaconda from `.zshrc` and `zshrc.pre-oh-my-zsh`, then executed `git checkout master && git pull && bundle && yarn`on the repo dir, and it started working! Thanks